# MongoDB Resume Old Query or Skip to Document

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am working on a system in which a user is able to query my MongoDB database using a number of parameters. When a user queries, they get 20 results. However, a user may want to get an additional 20 results, and then another, etc...

My first instinct when programming such a system was to use the "skip" function, and to skip the number of results I had returned to the user; However, the issue with this is that many (either hundreds or thousands of) new documents matching the user's query will have likely been added to MongoDB in the time it takes the user to run a new query to get the new results.
Thus, a "skip" won't resume the query where it last let off.

Eg.

```
Documents:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14, etc...
```

We leave off at document number 20. The user's next query says to skip 20. However, 500 new documents have been added. Now the skip should be 520, in order to pick up the query where it last let off. However, I currently have no way of tracking how many documents have been added since the user last queried.

My next thought was to have the user submit the Id of the last document received in the last query, as well as the total number of documents that the user has received over all of his queries. I would tell MongoDB to "skip" for the total number of documents received by the user - 1. I would then compare each document to the Id of the document sent by the user, until I found where the user left off.

Example:

```
public static String getDocument(String lastId, int skip, BasicDBObject query)
{
   DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query).skip(skip);
   while(cursor.hasNext())
   {
      BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
      String id = obj.getString("id");
      if(id.equals(lastId))
      {
         //Then we know that here is where we left off, and to start getting new documents
      }
    }
}
```

This, I assume, is inefficient if many new documents have been added, and could likely make query times slow. Is it correct to assume this?

Is there a way to query MongoDB, telling it to skip all results before a given document Id? If not, is there a standard way of dealing with such an issue? I am at a loss as to what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question. I don't know why have you mentioned an "aggregation" here, from your example I see its a mongo regular query, so I assume your question is about mongo queries and not about the aggregation framework.

In order to answer your question (at least as I understand it), at first I would like to provide some "tips-and-tricks" like information here.

In mongo db there are more reasons to avoid skipping for a large amount of objects and this is due to the fact that when you use"skip X" the querym, the engine has to iterate over all X objects (linear scan) before getting to the object X.
So if you retrieve, say 200 objects and use skip, the time to get these 200 objects will gradually will grow as skip value grows.

This is not unique to mongo, btw, this occurs also in relational database.

One preferred way to work with Mongo at this area is to return ordered results by something that you don't care but something that has an index on it (like _id, for example).

Note, that from the query you're only iterating over the whole bunch of results, and you don't really care about the order of these results.
So what you can do in this case is:

```
getNResults ordered by id (ascending)
while(shouldRetrieveMoreResults()) {
    memorize the last id in the list of retrieved results
    instead of skip, use the following query: "get 200 objects ordered by id  ascending where id > _a_memorized_id"
    memorize the last id among retrieved ids and perform the loop again and again
}
```

Since _id always has an index on it, the query will be fast and will be much more efficient for large skip values.

This is what's written in mongo db book, btw :)

Now what you raise here is another concern. Basically you say that you have constantly changing data.
In this case, maybe the best would be adding some "auxiliary" field to the document a field that would always increase, like time, so that you would iterate over values by time. The time can be indexed. So you might want to use the same trick I've described above, but instead of using ordering by object id, use ordering by another indexed field.

Hope this helps